# Inserting values into a table with a PHP-variable name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm setting up a simple website where each user gets their own table (bad idea, I know), in which other users can put comments into - like a super budget version of a Facebook-wall.

This is what my query looks like when I create the table:

```
$userTable = mysqli_query($conn, "CREATE TABLE `".$epost."`(
        ID INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        eMail VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        comment VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
        timestampp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        )");
```

However, when I try to take the values from a form, and insert them into the specific table they can't seem to find their way in there. Here's my code of that:

```
    <?php

include 'connect.php';

/*if(isset ($_POST['userUser']))*/

$valueEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userEmail']);
$valueUser = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userUser']); /*have the user to input the name, so i can connect to the correct DB*/
$valueMessage = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userMessage']);

$findUserTable = "SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE Firstname = '$valueUser'";
$findUserEmail = mysqli_query($conn, $findUserTable);

if(mysqli_num_rows($findUserEmail) > 0) /*finding the name of the persons email*/
    {
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findUserEmail))
        {
            $email = $result['Email'];
        }
    }

/* VALIDATION HERE */

$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$email." (eMail, comment) VALUES ('$valueEmail', '$valueMessage')"; /* wrong query?*/

header("refresh:10 url=userProfil.php");
/*echo '<script>alert("Meddelande skapat!");</script>';*/

echo $sql;

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

I've been trying different 'versions' of the variable, like ".$email.", `'.$email.'` and `".$epost."`. I get the correct name when i echo out my query or just the variable - but it can't seem to find the table?
I'm very aware that my code smells badly, so please spare me on that point.

Comment: forget to execute insert query!! use `mysqli_query($conn,$sql)`;

Comment: @Saty - Thanks for your response. Do you mean something like this?

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

Quite new at this, sorry if I'm just causing confusion.

Comment: The use of `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not always safe. Use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just simple write your query forget to execute it.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$email." (eMail, comment) VALUES ('$valueEmail', '$valueMessage')"; /* wrong query?*/
```

Use this

```
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);//for execute
```

Better use Bind and prepare statement as

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$email." (eMail, comment) VALUES (? ,?)"; /* wrong query?*/
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $valueEmail, $valueMessage);
/* Execute the statement */
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->affected_rows;
if ($row > 0) {
    echo "data inserted";
} else {
    "error";
}
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Yeah, this solved my problem. Thanks a lot, have a nice day!

Comment: Why downvote ?? can you have dare to explain reason??